# Is this polynomial in a finite field irreducible?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials

Let $\mathbb{F}:= \{a_1, \ldots , a_n \}$ be a finite field. Consider the following polynomial $$f = \prod_{i = 1}^n (X-a_i) + 1 $$ Is this polynomial irreducible? If not, is it irreducible in $\mathbb{F}_p$, a finite field with $p$ Elements for a prime $p$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde: I think you are mistaken. That question is about the existence of some irreducible polynomial of degree$~n$, which is definitely true, but this is about a particular one. That one happens to have no roots in the finite field, but this does not suffice to show it is irreducible. As far as I can see nobody at that question said whether this one is always irreducible or not (I would be the latter).

Comment: @DietrichBurde: could you be more precise about where the argument for irreducibility is given? I might be sleepy this morning, but I really could not find any after looking twice.

Comment: We have $f=(x^{p^n}-x)+1$, which is irreducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$ only when $n=1$, or $n=p=2$. This is answered [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122274/why-xpn-x1-is-irreducible-in-mathbbf-p-only-when-n-1-or-n-p-2).

Comment: The question isn't answered, or is it?

Comment: For $n\ge 2$, or $n\ge 3$ and $p\ge 3$ it is reducible over $\mathbb{F}_p$, hence also over $\mathbb{F}$. So the question is answered, I think.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand why? Why is the polynomial of @DietrichBurde the same as mine?

Comment: The product of all linear factors $(x-a_i)$ in a finite field equals $x^{p^n}-x$, see  [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565135/finite-fields-existence-of-field-of-order-pn-proof-help). So $f-1=(x -a_1)\cdots (x -a_{p^n})=x^{p^n}-x$.

Comment: If $\mathbb{F}$ is a finite field then it has $p^n$ elements and it is the splitting field of $x^{p^n}-x = \prod_{a \in \mathbb{F}} (x-a)$ whose coefficients are in $\mathbb{F}_p$ so yes it is answered