# How do Galois fields of sizes other than powers of primes behave?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, finite-fields

I understand how Galois fields of prime powers (e.g. $GF(2^8)$, $GF(17)$, $GF(257)$) behave. What I could never figure out is how they behave with sizes other than simple powers of primes. For example, $GF(15)$, $GF(100)$, or $GF(2^43^5)$.

Is it even possible?

Searching for this yielded no results.

Comment: "Is it even possible?" No. See [Order of finite fields is $p^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72856/order-of-finite-fields-is-pn)

Answer (score 2):

The order of any finite field is a prime power. Further, there is only one field (up to isomorphism) of a given finite order, if such a field exists.

Comment: Also existence is a duplicate, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565135/finite-fields-existence-of-field-of-order-pn-proof-help).